# Exported a modified Report from dev to test. Now report complains about missing parameter values

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I've updated a report (Data provider based) to include new parameters. The report runs perfectly on the dev environment so I exported it via XPO to the test environment (including all tables and classes). Now when I try to run the report I'm getting a slew of errors stating that parameter X is missing a value.

I know how to fix these. The problem is that one of them is my newly added parameter which I've confirmed via debugging is assigned a value.

Even after multiple:

- Forward and CIL compiles
- Cache clearings
- Re-deploys
- Re-imports
- Service restarts

the problem persists.

UPDATE: I've tried a Full Build + Full CIL Compile as well. Clearing the XPPIL folder and doing another full build + full cil isn't an option at the moment. So I've gone and set all the parameters to "AllowEmpty" and "Nullable" which does get rid of the error messages. But the core problem persists as I have expected: The parameter I added is not receiving the value from the contract.

Comment: Is this a modified `SYS/SYP` report or a completely custom one? Is there a business logic class? Have you tried a full AXBuild & full CIL? Reports can be a pain.

Comment: @AlexKwitny it's the SalesInvoice report. Forgot to mention it. So with a Business Logic class. Haven't tried those two. Will do...

Comment: @AlexKwitny Did both a full build and full CIL. Still the same errors...

Comment: Try moving via model instead of XPO? Try deleting the contents of your XPPIL folder. There really isn't any information for me to go on here.